# How to rotate built in display in 18.04 (without losing external monitor !)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-rotation

I have a similar setup to the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096061/how-to-change-orientation-of-built-in-display-in-ubuntu-18-04), laptop in tent mode with external monitor on HDMI. It is no longer possible to specify the built-in display orientation via the GUI (why ?) and when I use xrandr to force it inverted, the external display shuts off.

This configuration did work fine in 16.04. Acer Aspire R14, external monitor on HDMI.